# Encapsualting an event into a method?

Tags: c#, methods, event-handling, c#-2.0

Let's say, I can not modify class A.

I have this in a `class A<T>`, there is a `JumpNext()` method:

```
public void JumpNext();
```

It fires an event in `class A<T>`, called `Next`

And this in my class B:

```
public T Next()
{
    instanceofA.JumpNext();
    //instanceofA.Next += something;
    // wait for event
    // someting(object sender, AEventArgs e)
    //return e.Entry
}
```

The problem is, that my `Next` method has to return the instance of `T` contained in the `Entry` field of `AEventArgs` returned by the `A.Next` event.

So how can I do this inside one method in class B?

I'm using .NET 2.0, but if it is indeed possible in any later version only, that might be fine also.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to handle the A.Next event inside the B.Next() method.  You can do that with an [anonymous method,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k(VS.80).aspx) but you must be careful not to register the event handler more than once:

Say the Next event is defined as a delegate declared thusly:

```
public delegate vote NextHandler(object sender, AEventArgs e);
```

you could do:

```
public T Next()
{
    T entry;
    NextHandler handler = delegate(object sender, AEventArgs e) {
        entry = e.entry;
    }

    instanceOfA.Next += handler;
    try {
        instanceOfA.JumpNext();
    } finally {
        instanceOfA -= handler;
    }

    return entry;
}
```

Comment: Good call on using the finally clause in case JumpNext throws an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like that :

```
    public void T Next()
    {
        T value = default(T);
        EventHandler<AEventArgs> handler = new EventHandler<AEventArgs>(delegate(object sender, AEventArgs e) { value = e.Entry; });
        instanceofA.Next += handler;
        instanceofA.JumpNext();
        instanceofA.Next -= handler;
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: Beat me by one minute.  I would note that the lamba function syntax isn't a feature of C#2.0, so Thomas Levesque's solution would require you use a newer version of the framework.  A good discussion of the difference is at http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/01/10/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-one.aspx.

Also note you need to handle the possibility that JumpNext() throws, hence the finally block in my solution.

Comment: @Jonathan : Thanks for the edit ;) - @anelson : yes, it would be better to use a try/finally block, I only omitted it for the sake of simplicity...

Comment: This still uses a lambda expression, which is C# 3.0. This wouldn't work in C# 2.0: delegate (sender, e) => { value = e.Entry; }. It should be: delegate (sender, e) { value = e.Entry; }

Comment: Yes... rolling back to my previous version ;)

Answer (score 0):

I did the combination of the two:

```
public T Next()
{
    T entry = default(T);
    EventHandler<AEventArgs> handler = delegate(object sender, AEventArgs e)
    { 
        entry = e.Entry; 
    };
    instanceofA.Next+= handler;
    try
    {
        instanceofA.JumpNext();
    }
    finally
    {
        instanceofA.Next-= handler;
    }
    return entry;
}
```